# Regex - format HH:MM , Hours >= 24 , negative value

Tags: c#, asp.net, regex

I want to create a regex for this particular pattern:

- It should start with '+'or '-' or nothing.
- Number or hours . It can start with '0' (e.g. 00 => 0 , 1 => 1 , 01
  =>1, 0000089 => 89)
- Followed by ':'
- Then, the number of minutes. (Max 59, also it can start with only a '0' character , 09 => 9, 9
  => 9)

This is what I've got so far:

```
    private string regexPattern = @"^" + // Start of string (anchor)
                                 "(" + // begin capturing group
                                 "(+|-)?" + // "+" or "-" - is optional
                                 "(0*)?" + // a "0" - is optional
                                 "[0-9]*" + // accepts any number of digits
                                 ")" + // end capturing group
                                 ":" + "(" + // start capturing
                                 "[0 - 5]" + // character between 0 and 5
                                 "\\d" + // one digit
                                 ")" + // end group
                                 "$"; // end of string anchor
```

But I'm getting a syntax error:

> System.ArgumentException : parsing "^((+|-)?(0)?[0-9]+):([0 - 5]\d)$"
>   - Quantifier {x,y} following nothing.

I don't know if my pattern is correct created.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: you need to `escape` the `+` as `\+` or as per your language in `(+|-)`

Comment: you also need to remove spaces in between `[0 - 5]`. It should be `[0-5]`

Comment: a regex is not the right tool to parse a hour value. The values in the regex have context, when that is the case there are better tools. When using c#, DateTime.TryParse is a better option. Recognizing 24 vs 34 vs 25 makes your regex very complex.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few things in your regex that need to be improved, so lets start with the full pattern: `^((?:\+|-)?[0-9]+):([0-5]?\\d)$`

I have:

- escaped the `+`-sign and made `(?:\+|-)?` a non-capturing group - but you could also use `[+-]?`, pattern would then be `^([+-]?[0-9]+):([0-5]?\\d)$` - just wanted to point out the missing escape
- removed `(0*)?` as its already captured by `[0-9]+`
- changed `[0-9]*` to `[0-9]+`, as there should be at least one number before the colon
- removed the spaces from `[0 - 5]` and made it optional (single digit numbers seem to be valid from your question) => `[0-5]?`

Comment: I changed a little bit your pattern:  ^(((?:\\+|-)?[0-9]+):([0-5]?\\d))?$

In case of empty string I want to match my pattern. 
All my unit tests passed. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The immediate cause of the error is that you have to escape `+`: `\+`. The suggested pattern is

```
  // Note \+ instead of just +
  String pattern = @"^(\+|-)?[0-9]+:[0-5]?[0-9]$";
```

Explanation

```
   (\+|-)?     - either + or - or nothing
   [0-9]+      - any digits, but at least 1, note that 000089 matchs [0-9]+
   :           - semicolumn 
   [0-5]?[0-9] - 0..59 with 00..09 possibility
```

you haven't provide code where you use the groups, so I've dropped them; however you can easily restore groups if you want, e.g.

```
  String pattern = @"^(?<hours>(\+|-)?[0-9]+):(?<minutes>[0-5]?[0-9])$";
```